# Add prefix file using UNC path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to add a prefix to existing files within a UNC path. For some reason my code is changing the first character of the file name instead of appending it

Existing file names:

```
assignActivities-20170609100439.dat
assignActivities-20170609094939.dat
```

Desired file names:

```
SassignActivities-20170609100439.dat
SassignActivities-20170609094939.dat
```

Command:

```
REN `\\server.com\hostfiles\Export\Semaphore\assignActivities-*.dat S*.dat`
```

Resulting file names:

```
SssignActivities-20170609100439.dat
SssignActivities-20170609094939.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

`REN` doesn't have an "insert" mode, so it's overwriting the first character. You want to do the following instead:

```
FOR %v IN ('dir /b /a-d "\\server.com\hostfiles\Export\Semaphore\assignActivities*.‌‌​​dat") DO REN "%v" "S%~nxv"
```

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't work. I'm running this from command line, not batch.

'LFNFOR' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Windows command prompt. This will be executed from a SQL Server job using CmdExec. I'm testing locally on my laptop

Comment: Ok, try it without the LFNFOR then, and it should work. Edited my answer to add this info.

Comment: Nothing happens when I remove LFNFOR. No errors, it just executes and doesn't rename the files. Tried on Windows and SQL

Comment: It says The syntax of the command is incorrect. It's trying to append the S before the UNC path instead of the filename



C:\>REN "\\server.com\hostfiles\Export\Semaphore\assignActivities-20170609094939.dat" "S\\server.com\hostfiles\Export\Semaphore\assignActivities-20170609094939.dat"
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: You'll need to use `S%~nxv` as the new name.  (The `~nx` tells it to leave out everything but the Name and eXtension.)

Comment: I think @elzooilogico posted to you an [answer here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7913#p52602)

Comment: @elzooilogico should come here and answer, and I'll be happy to delete my answer.

Comment: Quite magnanimous of you, @elzooilogico